# Create a single PDF binder from multiple filemaker container fields combined with PDFs generated from filemaker layouts

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, acrobat, filemaker

I have not written any code yet as I am still perplexed as to the approach. My challenge is to generate a multipage PDF document combining PDFs generated using the PDF engine within filemaker (This part is easy, its built into filemaker using the append PDF document script) together with multiple attachments from within the same filemaker database, which are in container fields... These documents are a mixture of PDFs, TIFFs and JPEGs

The resulting file would be one PDF in sequence with all of the layouts and attachments together, renamed and placed on the desktop or preselected folder.

Comment: "*This part is easy, its built into filemaker using the append PDF document script*" Right. So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Is the problem in including stored images into PDFs? Just display the image container on a layout and save it to pdf, which you can attach, same as the other PDFs.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you can't in the way that you envisage it

You would need to use some external process to add (concatenate) a list of completed files together. ScriptMaster and iText would be your friend here.